# In R, how to pass arguments from the parent to the child function?

Tags: r, nested

I have two functions nested in another function and I would like that the arguments declared in parent were passed to the child (only when the argument is relevant to the function).

```r
# child function 1
child_f1 <- function(x1 = 1, x2 = 3) {
  res <- x1^2 + 4 * x2
}

# child function 2
child_f2 <- function(z = 2) {
  res <- z * 1.345
}

# parent function
parent_f <- function(y = 4, ...) {
  res <- (child_f1(...) ^ y) + child_f2(...)
  # print(res)
  return(res)
}
```

Test below:

```r
parent_f(y = 2, x1 = 2, x2 = 0, z = 3)
# Error in child_f1(...) (from #2) : unused argument (z = 3)

# Expected result:
(((2)^2 + 4*(0)) ^ (2)) + (3) * 1.345
[1] 20.04
```

How do I tell `child_f1` that has to use only `x1` and `x2` (if available, otherwise use default value) and `child_f2` that has to use only `z`(if available, otherwise use default value)?

I would like to stick with the usage of `...` rather than re-write a `parent_f()` with all the possible parameters declared.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add ... to each child to slurp up the unused arguments.  parent_f is unchanged.

```
child_f1 <- function(x1 = 1, x2 = 3, ...) {
  res <- x1^2 + 4 * x2
}

child_f2 <- function(z = 2, ...) {
  res <- z * 1.345
}

parent_f(y = 2, x1 = 2, x2 = 0, z = 3)
## [1] 20.035
```

If you can't modify the children or the parent then use this:

```
child_f1_orig <- child_f1
child_f1 <- function(x1 = 1, x2 = 3, ...) child_f1_orig(x1 = x1, x2 = x2)

child_f2_orig <- child_f2
child_f2 <- function(z = 2, ...) child_f2_orig(z = z)

parent_f(y = 2, x1 = 2, x2 = 0, z = 3)
## [1] 20.035
```

Comment: Very interesting - and I think this is also the answer that carries the less invasive solution.

Comment: I like this as well, as long as you have control over the child functions. If not, then the `formals`-approach may be the only practical option.

Comment: Have added an option if you can't modify parent or children.

Answer (score 2):

We can use `formals` to reduce the arguments to those supported by the child function. This relies on all arguments being named, which is supported here. After that, we use `do.call` to programmatically call a function with a list of arguments.

```r
# parent function
parent_f <- function(y = 4, ...) {
  dots <- list(...)
  dots1 <- dots[intersect(names(dots), names(formals(child_f1)))]
  dots2 <- dots[intersect(names(dots), names(formals(child_f2)))]
  res <- (do.call(child_f1, dots1) ^ y) + do.call(child_f2, dots2)
  # print(res)
  return(res)
}

parent_f(y = 2, x1 = 2, x2 = 0, z = 3)
# [1] 20.035
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It works for me. I tested the same function removing all (or some of) the arguments and the calculation uses (as you would expect) the default values. Brilliant solution.

Comment: I have accepted the answer from another user as it requires the minimum effort, but really thank you for this - I will definitely bear in mind the usage of `formals` in the future.

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of `formal` and design a proper function for your usecase

```
use_fun_with_args <- function(fun, ...) {
  dots <- list(...)
  do.call(fun, args = dots[intersect(names(formals(fun)), 
                                     names(dots))])
}

# parent function
parent_f <- function(y = 4, ...) {
  res <- (use_fun_with_args(fun = child_f1, ...) ^ y) + use_fun_with_args(fun = child_f2, ...)
  # print(res)
  return(res)
}
parent_f(y = 2, x1 = 2, x2 = 0, z = 3)
#> [1] 20.035
```

Comment: I think this will mis-assign `NA` where the formals have default values and `dots` does not include it. For instance, try with `parent_f(y = 2, x1 = 2, z = 3)`, where the removed `x2` has a default value in `child_f1` that should be used.

Comment: good spot! I adopted the function, basically, mimicing your logik. Not much of an improvement to your solution though besides having it functionlised